# Show that an integral is analytic

Tags: complex-analysis

Could somebody please help my with this problem, I am not sure how to do it, I never integrate function of two variables before
et $U$ denote an open set in $\mathbb{C}$. Let $f :\thinspace U \to
 \mathbb{C}$ be analytic, 
    define $F :\thinspace U\times U \to \mathbb{C}$ by
    $$
 F(z,w) = \begin{cases}
 \frac{f(w)-f(z)}{w-z} & z\neq w \\
 f'(z) & z=w.
 \end{cases}
 $$
Let $\gamma$ be a closed rectifiable curve in $U$. Prove that the function $g(z) = \int_\gamma F(z,w)\,dw$ is analytic on $U$. I have shown that F is analytic in w and z. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for editing my LaTex =)

Comment: The way to show that a parameter-dependent integral is analytic is usually Morera's theorem.

Comment: Ok. Thanks for the hint.